# iTextSharp Digital signature no need to input password after first sign

Tags: c#, windows, itext, digital-signature, digital

My simple windows desktop application to sign PDF with iTextSharp using smartcard will ask to input password when signing the PDF document. But it will not ask for password again when sign another PDF if the application does not exit.

How can I force the user to input password each time I sign document?

Eric

Comment: By *password* you mean the pin to activate signing on your smart card?

Comment: Yes. It just ask for one time when signing on smart card if the application keep opening.  How can force to prompt every time?

Comment: How do you access the smart card exactly? Are there any driver settings? What kind of smart card do you have? Is it for multiple signatures or for single signatures only?